# What sickness did the alliance chief have?

Tags: the-breaker

In the manhwa The Breaker: New Waves, after the new chief of the martial arts alliance confronted Goomonryong after his return to Seoul, he suddenly became so sick that he is going to die. I am really wondering what his sickness/injury was? I haven't seen in the manga the explanation what his injury/sickness is and what the effect of that injury would be. Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I am referring to the new chief of the alliance in The Breaker: New Waves.

Answer (score 1):

Kang-Sung took some "deadly" hits during his fight with Goomonryong.

He couldn't always use his reflection technique to counter the attacks, first example in chapt 142 by kicking him in the air.

After that he took a huge amount of hits, Goomonryong is strong enough to destroy a building so.. imagine the effect on a human :)

Imo the final hit chapt 143 is the one that caused the more damages.

Comment: actually i don't seem this is the right answer, Goomonryong's attack are physical based damage, while Kang-Sung took damage from his chi as what as the Ghost doctor defined, there should be some kind of explanation on why his chi was severely damaged. one example that i aim on finding is that the Soul Crushing strike causes bones to be broken something like that.